Multiply 2 input fields and show totalAmount in another input field
I want to calculate and show the totalAmount when Amount and Quantity is entered.
I am using (keyup) in expense.amount as I want to show as-is in expense.totalAmount. Using (ngModelChange) does not show the amount correctly for some reason.
I want the calcAmount() to begin only if quantity is changed.
Here is my updated HTML:
<div class="col-auto">
  <label for="charges">Amount</label>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="expense.amount" (keyup)="calcQuantity()" >
</div>
<div class="col-auto">
  <label for="quantity">Qty</label>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="expense.quantity" (ngModelChange)="calcQuantity()">
</div>
<div class="col-auto">
  <label for="totalAmount">Total</label>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="expense.totalAmount">
</div>

Here is my TS file:
calcQuantity() {
  this.expense.quantity = 1;
  this.expense.totalAmount = this.expense.quantity>1?(this.expense.amount||0)*(this.expense.quantity||0):this.expense.amount;
}

What is happening:
When I enter 100 in amount, it shows 100 in totalAmount. I want it this way. Quantity is 1 by default.
Issue:
If I change Quantity from 1 to 5, totalAmount remains 100. It should be 500.

It's because you are setting the quantity always to 1 before calculating the total amount, no matter what was entered!

The problem is the order of attributes. Your (ngModelChange) event fires before [(ngModel)] does. Which means inside your calcQuantity() function, the this.expense.quantity attribute still holds the old value. Also after this function is executed, [(ngModel)] sets the newly entered value. For more information, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234
The solution is to move the (ngModelChange) event after the [(ngModel)]:
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="expense.quantity" (ngModelChange)="calcQuantity()">

Also you always set the quantity to 1 before calculating the total amount, regardless of what quantity was entered by the user. To ensure that the value is not null or undefined, you can use the nullish coalescing assignment (??= operator) to set a default value in that case:
this.expense.quantity ??= 1;


Thank you but that didn't work. I have updated my question. Please check.

I'm getting this error when i remove that line:
`error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
44     this.expense.totalAmount = this.expense.quantity>1?(this.expense.amount||0)*(this.expense.quantity||0):this.expense.amount;`

@ElaineByene updated my answer

Thank you so much :)
I never knew about double ?? before.
